# Какова синтаксическая роль слова "оба"?

Tags: грамматика

**Немного информации**.

Слова оба/обе относятся к **собирательным числительным**. Кроме значения совместности, они имеют дополнительное значение  **указания на уже упомянутые предметы и лица**. По поводу слов оба, обе в науке **нет единого мнения**. Одни лингвисты считают их указательными местоимениями в значении и тот и другой, другие относят их к собирательным числительным на том основании, что они по значению близки числительному двое.

**А какова синтаксическая роль этих собирательных числительных** (или местоимений) в различных предложениях, например:  (1) Я был озлоблен, он угрюм, игру страстей **мы** знали **оба**.  (2) Поданы заявки на **оба** конкурса. Они, **оба молодые, темпераментные, оба смелые, оба запевалы**, стали зачинщиками всех отрядных затей.

Интересно то, что "оба" могут относится к местоимениям, существительным, прилагательным. Также они употребляются в значении существительного, в том числе в обособленных оборотах. (4) Поздним вечером Катя и Анна Фёдоровна, **обе** в старых тёплых халатах, сели на гобеленовый диванчик...).

К примеру, мне встретился такой разбор:http://spelling.siteedit.ru/page33/

**обоих (учеников)**: числительное, начальная форма ― оба,
постоянные признаки: количественное, собирательное, простое,
непостоянные признаки: муж.род, Р.п.,
синтаксическая роль: **часть дополнения**.

О какой части дополнения здесь говорится?

Comment: Видимо, (единственно) возможная роль словосочетания "обоих учеников"  в каком-либо предложении там рассматривается как _"дополнение"_ (ввиду имеющегося падежа оно не может быть подлежащим). Соответственно,  "обоих" может быть "частью" только дополнения.

Comment: Alex_ander, но  "оба" это всё-таки числительное, как и двое. Два ученика, двое учеников, оба ученика, двух учеников, двоих учеников, обоих учеников -  разве это не сочетания (счетные обороты) , которые в предложении являются одним членом?  Другое дело, что "оба" не всегда ведет себя как  числительное. Если заменить: "они, и тот и другой смелые...", "оба" по функции похоже на определение.

Answer (score 1):

> К примеру, мне встретился такой
>   разбор:http://spelling.siteedit.ru/page33/
>
> **обоих** (учеников): числительное, начальная форма ― оба, постоянные признаки: количественное, собирательное, простое, непостоянные
>   признаки: муж.род, Р.п., синтаксическая роль: **часть дополнения**.

.

Гм… Весьма странный разбор!

Во-первых, определить падеж словоформы ***обоих*** можно только при разборе предложения, в котором употреблено словосочетание ***обоих учеников***.

Во-вторых, при любом падеже **частью дополнения** слово ***обоих*** в этом словосочетании называть неправильно. Правильно: **определение**.

.

Пример:

> *Вдруг в один прекрасный день отворяется дверь классной комнаты, и в нее входит дюжий, грубый матрос и вводит за шиворот **обоих
>   учеников**.*

Здесь оба слова в словосочетании ***обоих учеников*** стоят в винительном падеже. Прямое дополнение ― *учеников*, а ***обоих***  ― **определение** к нему, словосочетание свободное.

.

Другой пример:

> *У **обоих учеников** имелись собственные обязанности, и Артур думал о том, что за задание будет отведено ему.*

Здесь оба слова в словосочетании ***обоих учеников*** стоят в родительном падеже. *(У) учеников* ― дополнение, ***обоих***  ― **определение** к нему, словосочетание свободное.

.

Из комментария в этой теме:

> *Два ученика, двое учеников, оба ученика, двух учеников, двоих учеников, обоих учеников* - разве это не сочетания (счетные обороты) ,
>   которые в предложении являются одним членом?

Одним членом в предложении будут являться только первые три словосочетания  ― с числительными, употреблёнными в форме именительного падежа: *два ученика, двое учеников, оба ученика.*

В словосочетаниях же *двух учеников, двоих учеников, обоих учеников* совпадения с именительным нет. Здесь имеем не неразложимые, а свободные словосочетания. *Двух, двоих, обоих* в этих сочетаниях  — **определения** к дополнению *учеников*.

Comment: Slava,  насколько я помню, для количественных числительных  связь такая: управление в И-В.п. и согласование в остальных падежах. Например: она занимается с двумя (обоими) учениками (Т.п.), это связь согласования. Но счетно-именной оборот всё равно рассматривается как единый член предложения, мы не выделяем в нем определение.

Comment: _Sibylla: Но счетно-именной оборот всё равно рассматривается как единый член предложения, мы не выделяем в нем определение._ === Нет, не все счётные обороты в косвенных падежах являются неразложимыми. Примеры неразложимых: _**около двадцати студентов, более двадцати книг**_...  Это не наш случай.

Comment: Вы уверены? Разбираем предложение: Она занимается  с двумя учениками. Учениками (какими?)  -  двумя. Это правильно?

Comment: _Sibylla: Разбираем предложение: Она занимается с двумя учениками. Учениками (какими?) - двумя. Это правильно?_ === **Абсолютно правильно!**

Comment: А вот в вузовском учебнике  (2009) написано, что "количественные числительные образуют с существительными словосочетания, которые выступают единым неделимым членом предложения".

Comment: _Sibylla: А вот в вузовском учебнике..._ === В каком именно? И какие примеры **неразложимых** количественно-именных сочетаний там приведены? **Не верю** в то, что в предложении  _"Она занимается с двумя учениками"_ авторы Вашего вузовского учебника считают  **неразложимым** сочетание  _"с двумя учениками"_.

Comment: Примера с учениками там нет, есть такие примеры: Лес горит уже два дня (обстоятельство),  девочка  лет четырнадцати    (определение), море... оставило на бреге тридцать три богатыря (дополнение).  Это неразложимые сочетания?  А  в других падежах (с тридцатью тремя богатырями) они что,   разлагаются на отдельные члены предложения?

Answer (score 0):

`Я был озлоблен, он угрюм, игру страстей мы знали оба.`

*«Мы оба»* подлежащее.

`Поданы заявки на оба конкурса.`

В таком варианте, как мне помнится, в школе нам бы сказали пометить *«на оба конкурса»* как определение (*какие* заявки?).

`Они, оба молодые, темпераментные, оба смелые, оба запевалы, стали зачинщиками всех отрядных затей.`

`Поздним вечером Катя и Анна Фёдоровна, обе в старых тёплых халатах, сели на гобеленовый диванчик...`

Здесь *«оба»* в роли подлежащего в поясняющих подчинённых предложениях.

`обоих (учеников)` «Обоих учеников» — дополнение, а «обоих» — соответственно, его часть.

---

Мне кажется, слово «оба» (чем бы оно ни было) неотделимо от согласованного слова и вместе с ним составляет один член предложения.

Comment: Спасибо, Ильдар, за ответ,  но для меня вопрос так и не прояснился.

Comment: Почему ж неотделимо? Знаю обоих учеников. Знаю (кого? )учеников, (каких?) обоих.

Comment: _«Обоих»_ — да. А _«оба»_?

Comment: Тем более, что Вы в своём ответе пишете, что количественные числительные (и _«оба»_) с существительным образуют один член предложения в именительном падеже...

Answer (score 0):

Sibylla,эти сайты-шпаргалки не следует воспринимать серьёзно, вот они и путают и учеников, и студентов.

Вот с этого же сайта: [РАЗБОР СЛОВА | spelling.siteedit.ru](http://spelling.siteedit.ru/razbor/)

Числительное шпаргалка на [Имена числительные | vk.com](http://vk.com/topic-41801109_27158620)

Числительные ДВА, ОБА, ПОЛТОРА.

Постоянные: количественное, подразряд (целое / собирательное / дробное), простое;

Вы видите, у них какое-то старое понимание, там разряды-только колич. и порядковое.

А вот это выражение:порядковые - определение (примыкают к существительным)

Это как понять? Что значит "примыкают"? Примыкают только неизменяемые слова. Или здесь в каком-то бытовом смысле?

В общем, зря Вы себя путаете, мозги напрягаете, у нас и так много всяких трудностей, а это просто левый сайт какой-то.

Количественные числительные в сочетаниях с именами существительными являются одним членом предложения в формах И.п. и В.п., сходного с ним. В остальных падежах они являются разными членами предложения. Ср.: На столе стояли (что?)три чашки. — На столе не хватало трех чашек. чего?-чашек, скольких?-трёх
-Подробнее на Referatwork.ru:

[Разряды числительных по построению и значению, склонение числительных | referatwork.ru](http://referatwork.ru/pravopisanie_russkogo_yazika/section-25.html)

Comment: Да, забыла указать, что "оба" сочетается так же, как и количественное, поэтому о синтаксической функции "оба" отдельно редко пишут.

Comment: Людмила, меня сайты мало интересуют,  приятнее и полезнее иметь дело с более солидными источниками. А вот в этих источниках я не могу найти нужной информации. На столе не хватало  (скольких) трех чашек. Это определение? Но в грамматике (Розенталь, например, современные учебники для вузов)  определения не отвечают на вопрос "скольких" (только какой, который, чей), они характеризуют предмет со стороны качества, признака или свойства, а из числительных   выражаться могут только порядковыми числительными. Получается, что количество чашек не является их признаком.

Comment: Розенталь пишет, что "оба" сочетаются с местоимениями (Например, "мы оба"), но  какая синтаксическая роль у это сочетания - информации нет. Меня как раз и огорчает, что не пишут о синтаксической роли "оба", а вот вопросы иногда задаются. И что же, придумывать ничем не подтвержденные ответы?