# Оба — местоимение или числительное?

Tags: морфология, части-речи, выбор-варианта

Оба — это местоимение или числительное? И почему?

Comment: Что говорит словарь?

Comment: Есть определения: Местоимение - самостоятельная часть речи указывающая на предметы, признаки и количества, но не называет их. Тут оба - те назвали сколько, уже не местоимение. А вот в учебнике написано, что это местоимение.

Comment: @Сибиряк Или можно поставить вопрос так: что говорит трёхтомник Шанского и Тихонова? Ведь потому и вопрос, наверное, что они говорят что-то разное.

Comment: См. обсуждение этой темы здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/428192/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Среди **количественных числительных** выделяется группа **собирательных** числительных, обозначающих количество предметов как одно целое: двое, трое, пятеро, семеро, **оба**, обе.
[Имя числительное](http://slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=5312&0a0=1715)

Среди собирательных числительных особое место занимает слово **оба** (обе).
Оно включается в собирательные числительные на основании его значения – "и тот и другой из двух названных". В слове **оба** (обе) кроме значения совместности (*мы оба; мы вместе друг с другом; и тот, и другой вместе*) присутствует местоименное (указательное) значение.
Подобно местоимениям, **оба** указывает на уже упоминавшиеся предметы или лица.

Вот примеры употребления этого слова, совмещающего значение количества (совокупности) с функцией указания:

*И вы, и я, мы **оба** порядочные люди* (Тургенев).

*Я был озлоблен, он угрюм;

Страстей игру мы знали **оба**:

Томила жизнь **обоих** нас;

В обоих сердца жар угас.*
Пушкин

По поводу слов ***оба, обе*** в науке нет единодушного мнения.

Значение слова **оба** по Ефремовой:
употребляется как местоименно-количественное слово; и тот и другой, и то и другое (из двух названных или известных предметов мужского или среднего рода).

Некоторые лингвисты считают, что **оба** следует относить к указательным местоимениям, так как оно имеет отличительные признаки от всех собирательных числительных и по сути является исключением: изменяется по родам, а также сочетается с одушевлёнными и неодушевленными существительными.

Comment: Ой, спасибо! Нечасто меня хвалят. В последнее время - всё чаще шпильки.

Answer (score 0):

[Толковый словарь Ожегова](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/129018) говорит, что ОБА - числительное.

Comment: Но ведь вопрос-то был "почему?". Нужно как-то аргументировать. Что пользы, если я скажу в ответе, что Н.М. Шанский и А.Н. Тихонов во втором томе "Современного русского языка" (учебник для пед. институтов, 1987 г.) утверждают, что это местоимение? Автор вопроса сам признаётся, что знает об этом.

Comment: @grizzly, Догадываюсь, что можно спросить кто? - оба и сколько? — оба, но не все же объяснять решения авторов словарей - это не моего уровня задача.

Comment: Ну, тогда это комментарий, а не ответ. Для ответа было бы лучше представить обе точки зрения (словарную и из учебника) и честно сказать, что это сложно объяснить.

Comment: @grizzly, Не спорю. Но теперь, с Вашей помощью, ответ вместе с комментариями что-то дает сердцу и уму?

Comment: Да, спасибо. (Если возможно, считайте мои комментарии здесь не столько против Вашего ответа, сколько в защиту спрашивающего.)

Comment: _Но ведь вопрос-то был "почему?". Нужно как-то аргументировать._ Забавно. А если выпускника средней школы попросят "аргументировать" какую-нибудь формулу квантовой механики? Почему-то считается, что на подобные вопросы может отвечать "аргументированно" чуть ли не любой. Таки нет. Поэтому лучшая рекомендация – смотреть в словари, причем верить позднейшим изданиям.